# Postgres - limit procedure run per session

Tags: postgresql

I got a scenario where I have a “pre-cook” procedure by date. If the data for that date is cooked, just return it, otherwise that procedure will cook it.

And the problem is that if the cooking process taking too long, there will be a chance that data will be duplicated.

I would be expect this workflow:

1. User A opens a session from the web-app and requests data for 2018-June, a procedure called `proc_A` will check the data for that month and cook it if it does not yet exist.
2. User B opens another session from the desktop-app and requests the same data for 2018-June, then they should get a message saying that the data is cooking, please wait.

Is it possible to achieve that by only doing changes in the PostgreSQL DB rather than making changes to the web-app and the desktop-app?

Comment: hmmm not quite sure if you can read the systems table , but you can create a task execution table and keep each task along with its state, so you'll need to change your overall process , look first at this table and in case the same task is already in execution state , then respond with 'please wait'

Comment: @AntJavaDev good idea, I will try that way, but still that mean I have to maintaining that table and put some script to all pre-cook procedures, I hope there would be a way for more cleaner, maintaining a task table is quite a up-skill knowledge, but thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a state column to the data table:

```
ready boolean DEFAULT FALSE
```

The workflow would be as follows:

```
INSERT INTO data (month, value, ready)
   VALUES (date_trunc('month', current_timestamp)::date, NULL, FALSE)
ON CONFLICT (month) DO NOTHING;
```

If a row gets inserted, proceed to cook the value, then run

```
UPDATE data SET
   value = 42, ready = TRUE
WHERE month = date_trunc('month', current_date)::date;
```

If no row gets inserted by the first statement, run

```
SELECT value, ready
FROM data
WHERE month = date_trunc('month', current_date)::date;
```

If `ready` is true, return the data, if not, tell the client to please wait.

Comment: Thanks for fixing my grammar, about your solution, I tried but when the second thread call the proc_A, it cannot perform dirty read on the extra column, the data only got updated when the first thread finished, I have to use dblink extension to achieve that, not sure it is the correct way or not, but thanks for your solution

Comment: I forgot to mention that you have to `COMMIT` after the first insert so that others can see the entry. Is that a problem?

Comment: yup sounds good, complies without error, but I need to do few more testing ^^